# RouterLink seems to just reload the current page most of the time

Tags: html, css, angular, navigation, routerlink

I have added page navigation in my webapp using routerlinks and for some reason the page just reloads most of the time , and at the other times it works fine, very randomly.

I am stumped, especially as to why it works randomly. Any insight at all would be helpful.

Relevant code:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfileComponent } from './views/profile/profile.component';
import { PwSetupComponent } from './views/pw-setup/pw-setup.component';
import { ChangePwComponent } from './views/change-pw/change-pw.component';
import { EditProfileComponent } from './views/edit-profile/edit-profile.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',   redirectTo: 'pwSetup', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'pwSetup', component: PwSetupComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
  {path: 'changePw', component: ChangePwComponent},
  {path: 'editProfile', component: EditProfileComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

pw-setup.component.html:

```
<div style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left:10px; ">
        <img src="./assets/img/og-favicon.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div class="container-fluid outer-container" style="height:80%;min-height:550px;">

        <div class="row middle-container">
           <div class="col-s-12 container inner-container">

        <p >Lets set up your password</p>
        <form >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username"  class="label1">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
                <p>email@id.com</p>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username"  class="label1">TEAM NAME</label>
                    <p>name of team</p>

                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password"  class="label1">PASSWORD</label>
                <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control"  />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password"  class="label1">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control"  />

            </div>
            <label class="label2"><input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" value="remember" type="checkbox" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button  mat-flat-button class="blue-button">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/profile']" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;" >PROCEED</a>

                </button>


            </div>

        </form>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatButtonModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatIconModule, MatSidenavModule, MatListModule, MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SideNavComponent } from './components/side-nav/side-nav.component';
import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { RightNavComponent } from './components/right-nav/right-nav.component';
import { HighchartsChartComponent } from 'highcharts-angular';
import { ProfileComponent } from './views/profile/profile.component';
import { PwSetupComponent } from './views/pw-setup/pw-setup.component';
import { ChangePwComponent } from './views/change-pw/change-pw.component';
import { EditProfileComponent } from './views/edit-profile/edit-profile.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SideNavComponent,
    RightNavComponent,
    HighchartsChartComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    PwSetupComponent,
    ChangePwComponent,
    EditProfileComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    AvatarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There are also no console errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `routerLink` directive applied to an `a` element sets an `href` attribute upon this element.


I guess the same exception is thrown on click but the event still bubbles up and then the default behavior is executed and the page location is changed. As this happens really fast, you don't notice the error.


Try preserving the console logs even after page relaod, the error should be there.

If error continues , try change `<a> tag` to `<button> tag` and check .

Comment: enabled preserve log, still shows no error, i get                                                 
 "Navigated to http://localhost:4200/pwSetup? "      when it doesn't work

Comment: try change `<a>` tag to `<button>` tag and check if the problem still remains or solved . through this we can check that problem is with routerLink or with `<a>` tag @BlackJack

Comment: seems to be working fine now, that routerLink has been added to ```<button>``` instead of  ```<a>``` ,thanks . But i still don't get why it didn't work with the ```<a>``` tag. What's with the setting of the href attribute ?

Comment: Please upvote and accept if it helped you . @BlackJack . Refer my answer you will get the reason why it sometime won't work with `a` tag .

Comment: an href is added automatically to the <a> tag , since according to my code, its an empty href . But it still points to the correct page to be navigated to .My question is, why does it still cause a page reload, that too only sometimes

Comment: update: explicitly setting href="javascript:void(0);" in <a> works perfectly too

Comment: Wow ... Thanks buddyy ... I will update my code so that future visitors gets proper answer .